# I used laravel groupBy, but i am trying to sort results by where have many grouped items

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to sort where grouped product_id which has many orders comes first:
Here are my codes:

```
$orderProducts = OrderProduct::where("seller_id", auth()->user()->id)->latest()->get()
            ->groupBy(function ($val){
                return $val->product_id;
});
```

Result is like:

```
 ` {
     "1": [
           {
            "id": 8,
            "order_id": "5",
            "product_id": "1",
         }],
     "2": [
           {
            "id": 9,
            "order_id": "5",
            "product_id": "2",
         },
        {
            "id": 10,
            "order_id": "5",
            "product_id": "2",
         }
]}
 `

And i want it sorted like: `
      { 
      "2": [
           {
            "id": 9,
            "order_id": "5",
            "product_id": "2",
         },
        {
            "id": 10,
            "order_id": "5",
            "product_id": "2",
         }
    ],
     "1": [
           {
            "id": 8,
            "order_id": "5",
            "product_id": "1",
         }],
    }
`
```

where product_id of 2 with many orders comes first and others are ordered according to orders they have. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have a collection, you can simply call the `sortByDesc()` method on the collection. Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-sortbydesc

```
$orderProducts = OrderProduct::where("seller_id", auth()->user()->id)
        ->latest()
        ->get()
        ->groupBy(function ($val){
            return $val->product_id;
        })->sortByDesc(function($object) {
            return $object->count();
        });
```

As you can see, I'm returning the count of the object's items array using the Laravel count() method.